# Issue with detecting Persian characters in TeXstudio

Tags: font-encodings

Why is LaTeX not detecting Persian characters when I'm using TeXstudio? I have already included the necessary packages and set the encoding to UTF-8. What could be causing this problem?[image]

Comment: There is nothing to do with LaTeX or any packages. This is happening because of your file encoding itself. You can use and test the same file with other editors or with simple Notepad to see what the encoding is.

Comment: @ Qaher
That file is not a standard LaTeX Unicode file.
Does not open properly with standard LaTeX editors. (TeXmaker, Notepad++ , ...) except the FarsiTeX editor. http://persian-computing.org/farsitex/
FarsiTeX has its own internal Unicode.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have a file with the `.ftx` extension,  it is a FarsiTeX file.

That file is not a standard LaTeX Unicode file.
Does not open properly with standard LaTeX editors. (TeXmaker, Notepad++ , ...) except the FarsiTeX editor. (download: persian-computing.org/farsitex )

FarsiTeX has its own internal Unicode.

There are three solutions.

1. Convert to unicode utf-8.
   (ftxe-0.12.py file in [xepersian package](https://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/xetex/latex/xepersian.zip).)
2. convert with bidiTeXmaker editor.
   (File menu -> Import Ftx files)
3. Install FarsiTeX.
   FarsiTeX /fa:r si tEk/ is a free Persian/English bidirectional typesetting system based on Donald [Knuth's TeX Program](http://sunburn.stanford.edu/%7Eknuth/). TeX and his friend METAFONT have served mathematicians and technical writers all over the world for many years and helped them to write prettier and easier.

A new experimental version of FarsiTeX is [out](http://sourceforge.net/project/showfiles.php?group_id=7710&package_id=179768&release_id=393598). Read the [release notes](http://sourceforge.net/project/shownotes.php?release_id=393598&group_id=7710) or download from the menu. Available in the release are a Windows installer, bundling the editor and makeindex utility too, the source tarball that can be used on Linux and other systems too, and a report/manual of the new features and changes.

teTeX/Unix/Linux [installation guide](http://persian-computing.org/farsitex/linux.html) is now available.

Unlike many other Persian document preparation systems, FarsiTeX is not only very powerful in mathematical typesetting but also takes advantage of the powers of a generic markup language.

FarsiTeX is [Free Software](http://www.gnu.org/philosophy/free-sw.html). It is protected by [GNU General Public License](http://www.gnu.org/copyleft/gpl.html), like many other great pieces of software.

If you use FarsiTeX extensively, or make money with it, please consider helping the project.